# React: Getting props to load on initial render

Tags: reactjs

`this.props.allStagesData` comes from an AJAX request in the parent component. If I comment out `console.log('stageID', currentStage._id);`, this component currently loads 3 times before I finally get the data. When that log is uncommented, it throws an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined`, because I don't yet have the data.

How can I get this data to load on initial render?

```
export default class NavMain extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      stagesData: []
    }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    var stagesData = this.props.allStagesData;

    this.setState({
      stagesData: stagesData
    })
  }
  render() {
    var  stagesData = this.state.stagesData,
         currentStage = _.find(stagesData, {'_status': "open"});

      console.log('this.props.allStagesData', this.props.allStagesData);
      console.log('this.state.stagesData', stagesData);
      console.log('currentStage', currentStage);
      console.log('stageID', currentStage._id);

    return (
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

[image: console]

(Disregard the two errors in the image, they are unrelated.)

Comment: If the data is only going to be available asynchronously, make sure that the parent component is setting some default value for it so you don't get the TypeError. Then, when it updates, the child component will simply update based on the value changing in the prop.

Comment: ^ this makes sense, I'm having the same issue now. But is there a way to circumvent it? Feels a bit dirty to put fake data in just to prevent an error being thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before your data is there, you can simply return something else, or `null`. Try adding `if(this.state.stagesData.length === 0) return null` to the first line of your render function. That way it will not display until the data is actually there.

Edit: To answer your question, the data can't be there on the first render. A better way to do this would be to return the HTML that has everything except your data, or simply null as stated above, until the request is finished. You can also render a loading indicator if you want!

Comment: Tried adding the if statement, but it never re-renders so the component never loads.

Comment: In your case you should not be using state at all. Remove constructor and componentWillMount. Inside the render replace this.state with this.props. I read your code too fast. Putting props into state is an anti-pattern and not needed. When the parent component updates the state, it will rerender this component that you have here.

Comment: OK, made the changes (including input from someone else trying to help) to:


const stagesData = this.props.allStagesData;

    if (!stagesData) {
      return null;
    }

    const currentStage = _.find(stagesData, {'_status': "open"});


but still see three attempts to render in the console before receiving data.

Comment: This is because a top level component, one that you haven't posted code for, is calling this.setState twice. The first log is the first render of the app, and then the other two are from setState being called.

Comment: aha! Yes, I had `this.state = { allStagesData: [] }` in the parent's constructor props. Removing that gave me my data right away and throws no errors. Thanks for the help!